# What is the correct order when multiplying both sides of an equation by matrix inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So my questions is let's say you were asked to solve for $A$, and you have something like this:

$$BAC=D$$ where B, C , and D are matrices. So the way I would solve this would be to multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$ (inverse of B and C), but since the order in the multiplication matters $A = DB^{-1}C^{-1}$ would be different than say $A = B^{-1}DC^{-1}$. My question (maybe stupid or I am just missing something) is how do you know which order is the correct one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must be sure to multiply on the correct side. To get rid of the $B$ in $BAC$, you must multiply **on the left** by $B^{-1}$, so you must do the same on the righthand side of the equation:

$$AC=B^{-1}BAC=B^{-1}D\;.$$

To get rid of the $C$ in $AC$, you must multiply $AC$ **on the right** by $C^{-1}$, so you must do the same thing on the other side of the equation:

$$A=ACC^{-1}=B^{-1}DC^{-1}\;.$$

Comment: A minor comment: "multiply on the left" is usually called "premultiply", while "multiply on the right" is usually called "postmultiply".

Comment: @Vedran: Both sets of terms are in common use. Given the elementary nature of the question, I chose the more elementary terminology.

Comment: Ok. I've seen more of pre/post-multiply. Anyway, my intention was to inform the OP, not correct you, since I assumed you knew that.

Comment: @Vedran: Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

You have to multiply $C^{-1}$ from the right ( on both sides) and $B^{-1}$ from the left ( on both sides). Which one you do first doesn't matter.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

To get from $BAC = D$, you left-multiply both sides by $B^{-1}$ and right-multiply both sides by $C^{-1}$, giving $B^{-1}BACC^{-1} = B^{-1}DC^{-1}$. Since $B^{-1}B = I$ and $CC^{-1} = I$, this simplifies to $A = B^{-1}DC^{-1}$.