# Order for Multiplying Matrix by Inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question that follows up on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448420/what-is-the-correct-order-when-multiplying-both-sides-of-an-equation-by-matrix-i)

That post answers the question that given:
$$BAC = D$$
We can calculate:

$$AC = B^{-1}D$$
$$BA = DC^{-1}$$
$$A = B^{-1}DC^{-1}$$

However, how can I calculate what $BC$ is equal to?

Comment: I don't think $BC$ can be calculated from here, insufficient information.

Comment: Note that this method only works if B and C are in fact invertible.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you can do is find $B$ and $C$, then multiply them together.

\begin{align}
BAC & = D\\
BACC^{-1} & = DC^{-1} \\
BAA^{-1} & = DC^{-1}A^{-1} \\
B& = DC^{-1}A^{-1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
BAC & = D\\
B^{-1}BAC& = B^{-1}D\\
A^{-1}AC & = A^{-1}B^{-1}D \\
C & = A^{-1}B^{-1}D
\end{align}

So $BC = B \cdot C$

\begin{align}
BC & = B\cdot C\\
& = DC^{-1}A^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}D
\end{align}

Done!

Comment: ...er, this isn't a solution. You haven't eliminated B and C from the right-hand side. Also, you're assuming that A, B, and C are all invertible, which isn't necessarily the case; we don't even know that they're square.